# Null Dereference Fortify Issue

Tags: java, fortify

I'm working on remediating fortify findings within a code base and the scan came back with a null dereference finding. The recommendation is that I add a null check to csvWriter, but to be honest I don't exactly know what that means. Could anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
    private void writeBadRecordFile() {

        CsvWriter csvWriter = null;

        try {
            badRecordFile = File.createTempFile("BadRecords", ".csv");
            badRecordFile.deleteOnExit();

                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(badRecordFile);

                csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, ',');
                String[] header = {"BIC"};

                csvWriter.writeRecord(header);

                for (String badRecord : badRecords) {

                    csvWriter.write(badRecord);
                    csvWriter.endRecord();
                }

                csvWriter.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorMessage = "Bad records were detected in the uploaded file, but the bad record file was not able to be created.";
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                csvWriter.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: whoops. thanks for that catch.

Comment: You should post the complete error message, stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

If the first three lines of your `try` block fail, then `csvWriter` is still `null`, and the `finally` block which runs `csvWriter.close` will throw `NullPointerException`. The linter is recommending that you do

```
if (csvWriter != null) {
  csvWriter.close();
}
```

in your `finally` block. Or, better, use Java's [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to forgo the problem entirely.